# RNetlogo - NLStart command error: Unable to locate empty model

Tags: r, netlogo

I'm unable to start Netlogo gui with the NLStart command in R.

I get the return:

> Unable to locate empty model: /system/empty.nlogo

The NetLogo window pops up and opening a model results in a black background and none of the buttons seems to work anymore. Loading a model through the NLLoadModel function doesn't work either.

```
library("rJava")
library ("igraph")
library("RNetLogo")
nl.path <- "C:/Program Files/NetLogo 6.0.3/app"
model.path <- "C:/Users/amcat/Desktop/R/ThesisABM.nlogo"
NLStart(nl.path, gui = TRUE, nl.jarname = "netlogo-6.0.3.jar")
Unable to locate empty model: /system/empty.nlogo
```

Comment: In addition to my question: Because the NetLogo window pops up, I tried loading one of the models from the library through clicking the buttons. This works. 

But when I want to open a new model, it gets the error that NetLogo is unable to locate empty model.

Opening my own model through Open, results in a black background and NetLogo that stops corresponding. I need to restart RStudio completely.

Comment: I had the same problem and what I did was load a model from library and then modify the code (you can delete it and work from 0). Then you can save the model or just setup with your modified new model. Hope it helps, at least in practice.